# Error messages are not getting displayed when trying to post data via JQuery in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Error messages are not getting displayed when trying to post data via `JQuery` but the same is happening when I am using `@Html.BeginForm()`.
I am using `jqgrid` here where on selecting user from the grid and clicking on delete all button, the users get deleted and if there is some error then error should be displayed on the screen.

View:

```
<div >
@Html.ValidationBootstrap()
</div>
<button type='button'  `onclick="DeleteAllUsers()"`><span>Delete All</span></button>

function DeleteAllUsers() {
            var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked')
                .map(function() {
                    return $(this).val();
                })
                .toArray();
            var act = "@Url.Action("DeleteAllUsers", "Admin")";
           $.post(act, { permId: checkedValues }, function (data) {
            alert(data.Message);
                });
        }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DeleteAllUsers(List<int> permId)
        {
            if (permId != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var id in permId)
                    {
                         AuthManagerServiceObj.DeleteApplicationPermissionByPermId(id);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error::" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error while deleting user :: Please select a user to delete.");
            }
            return Json(new { Message = "Error" });
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to make request if not what error are you getting in `console` ?

Comment: I am able to see the error when I put a debugger in my MVC application.. but I am not able to see the same error on my page in the browser...

Comment: What error are you getting in MVC app? and that mean you are able to make request, and check all `permId` are you getting in your `ActionResult` correctly(its not null or empty)

Comment: Yes... I am getting ActionResult and PermId correctly.. For example.. if user does not select anything and click on DeleteALL button.. then according to my code.. Error message: "Error while deleting user :: Please select a user to delete." should get displayed on the screen.. but it is not happening.. the page just refreshes and nothing gets displayed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved..instead of calling controller by jquery I called from Html.Begin form and it worked and now I can the errors.

@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteAllUsers", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { area = "", name = "DeleteSelectedUsersForm", id = "DeleteSelectedUsersForm" }))
        {
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

Check what you have to do

1. You are Redirecting on another page by writing this code you need to remove this.

   ```
   RedirectToAction("AdminPage", "Admin", new { @mode = 1 });
   ```

   and return like your error message

   ```
   return Json(new {Message="Your Message"});
   ```
2. Your post method like

   ```
   $.post(act, { permId: checkedValues }, function( data ) {
      alert(data.Message);
   });
   ```
3. Don't need to use `location.reload(true);`

Comment: I made these changes.. but still error in ModelState.AddModelError is not getting hit.

Comment: @Shivali Can you edit your edit your post with changed ?

Comment: Updated and I have changed return value of the controller from "return RedirectToAction("AdminPage", "Admin", new { @mode = 1 });" to return AdminPage();

Comment: You must have to return on same page why you are redirecting on another page, i wrote how you have to return `return Json(new {Message="Your Message"});`

Comment: I am returning to the same page and not another page.. I modified the code and replaced the return with return Json(new {Message="Your Message"}); but now.. I can see the message in the alert but again "ModelState.AddModelError" errors are not getting displayed in @Html.ValidationBootstrap().